# Xcode issues errors -AppIcon

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, appicon

I started the Udemy course for `Xcode` and Swift and I’m having these errors. I’m following the "right way" step by step.

[image]

Comment: You added appicon with Appicon-1 : by default it is Appicon which is used. You can remove old AppIcon or rename it AppIcon-orig. and then rename AppIcon-1 as AppIcon

Comment: Also Ptit Sav solution, you can select on App Target App Icons and Launch Images section. You can check SS at link.  https://www.hizliresim.com/q3n7xq1

Answer (score 0):

You have to removed 'Appicon-1' because Xcode read 'Appicon' by default. So you have to remove 'Appicon-1' first then set your app icons on 'Appicon' folder.